# CKEditor loop only works on the last instance

Tags: jquery, focus, ckeditor, instance

I'm trying to set a focus event on all my CKEditor textareas on the page. Here's the code that loads on jQuery document ready:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    alert(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('focus', function() {
        alert(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
        remove_invalidation(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
    });
}
```

(Note: remove_invalidation() is a function I wrote that just removes some CSS formatting on the textarea. It shouldn't affect the problem.)

I added a couple alerts to see what was happening. So, right away, as expected, when the document ready event kicks off this code, I get one textarea after another with the names of each of the CKEditor textareas. That works.

But, when I click inside any of the textareas to give them focus, the alert always pops up the name of the last textarea on the page.

Comment: What you have in Firebug or other console when running `console.log(CKEDITOR.instances);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    (function(i){
        alert(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('focus', function() {
           alert(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
           remove_invalidation(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

the issue was you are using the same i within each on focus event, and that i was getting incremented to the value for the last editor. Placing the code within an immediately executing function solves this problem by giving the code it's own scope.

Comment: Thanks! A coworker and I also just figured out a similar solution. We used the same code I had above, but inside the focus event function, we changed "CKEDITOR.instances[i]" to "this" and it worked for the same reason you described.

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrasing the [MDN article Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (section "Creating closures in loops: A common mistake"):

A number of closures have been created by the loop, but each one shares the
same single lexical environment, which has a variable with changing
values (`i`). The value of `i` is determined when the
`on('focus')` callbacks are executed. Because the loop has already run its
course by that time, the `i` variable (shared by all
closures) has been left pointing to the last entry in the `CKEDITOR.instances`
list.